# Past Continuous + Past Perfect?

Tags: tense, past-tense, past-continuous

Can we correct this sentence?: 
"When you were calling I had not had an internet connection".

I've decided that Past Perfect Tense in the second part of sentence is appropriate because an incident with a connection occurred before call starting and there was no internet connection during call. But i'm not sure.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean _when_ instead of _where_? That an incident occurred earlier makes no difference, _having an internet connection_ or not having one is something that lasts over a period of time. If you want to talk about the incident, you should mention the incident, not the result (no connection). Your title mentions _past continuous_, by the way. How is that relevant? You don't use any past continuous.

Comment: I use "were calling", i.e. Past Continuous.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I overlooked that, because your question seemed to be about the second part of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

If the internet was out *during* the call, past perfect is not correct, because the problem was ongoing - even if it *started* before. If the internet was restored before the call, but you were commenting on the outage that had just occurred before it "had not had" would be correct. However. . .

That sounds weird. "Had not had" is slightly awkward, you are using the same word in two different ways. To be specific enough for this case, but not awkward, I would say:

> Before you were calling I did not have an internet connection.

This would be correct in the same situation that the past perfect was, but without using the word "had" twice.